# Finding the same elements in an array and preventing duplicate counting

Tags: java, for-loop, duplicates, equals

Given the following code:

```
public static int countSames(Object[] a) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            if (a[i].equals(a[k]) && i != k) {
                count += 1;
                break; //Preventing from counting duplicate times, is there way to replace this?
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a solution which doesn't use **break statement** since I've heard its bad practice. 
But without the break this method returns 6 instead of wanted 3 for array {'x', 'x', 'x'}.

Comment: I don't think there's a strong consensus that `break` and `continue` are bad practice.

Comment: I think your requirement is not clear. What does it mean count the same?

Comment: Are the duplicates intended globally? For example what is the expected result for the input array {'x', 'x', 'x','y','y',y','z','z','z'}?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find the number of unique elements in the array try using this approach as it has only one loop and hence efficient.

```
    private static int findNUmberOfUnique(String[] array) {
        Set<String> set=new HashSet<>();
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            if(!set.contains(array[i])){
                set.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return set.size();
    }
```

Let me know if I did not understand your requirement clearly.

Comment: Don't call it findDup if it counts the number of unique elements. It doesn't find duplicates. Call it something like numOfUnique. And you might just want to initialize the set directly from the array `new HashSet<>(Arrays. asList(array));` so you don't have to loop at all.

Comment: @GonenI haha ofcourse, I thought I could help the person who raised the question with a simpler solution from his way of writing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a flag instead of `break`:

```
public static int countSames(Object[] a) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length && !found; k++) {
            if (a[i].equals(a[k]) && i != k) {
                count += 1;
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I am curious if there is any improvement if using `flag` instead of `break`?

Comment: @TranHo OP wanted to avoid using `break`. I offered an alternative. I don't think one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hashmap to find the same elements in an array and preventing duplicate counting.

```
class Solution {
public int[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    HashSet<Integer>hs=new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i:nums1)
        hs.add(i);
    HashSet<Integer>hs1=new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int j:nums2){ 
    if(hs.contains(j)){
        hs1.add(j);
    }
  }
    int[] res=new int[hs1.size()];
    int j=0;
    for(int k:hs1)
        res[j++]=k;


    return res;

}
```

}